# How to map a Windows user to root in WLS 2?

Tags: linux, windows-10, user-accounts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just upgraded Windows 10 to version 2004 which has WLS 2. It works great.

I do not understand however the relationship between users on Windows (say, `john`, the user I am logged to in Windows) and the ones in WLS (for instance `root`).

Specifically, I would like `john` to be mapped to `root` from the perspective of WLS. Or at least recognize `john` so that I can add it to the group `root`.

One of the reasons I need that for is to be able to access `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\root` directly from Windows

Comment: They are separate.  If you want to make `john` to have the same permissions `root` then you go about that as you would with any Linux distribution.  However, it's important to point out, how you access your WSL file system within Windows is well documented.  Trying to navigate to `\\wsl$Ubuntu-18.04\root` isn't it.

Comment: @Ramhound: not sur if I understand. You are saying that there is no relationship between the Win and Linux users, and then you mention that if i want `john` (a Windows user) to have the same access as root etc. → so are they related or not? Is there an implicit mapping based on names?  And yes, I ma navigating to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04` (OK) and then `root` (KO - permission denied)

Comment: john lives in "windows land" and has ZERO relationship with the accounts or permissions with your WSL/WSL2 accounts.  There is no mapping between them.  Also.. from a *nix point of view.. what you are implying is an abomination.. nobody needs direct access to the root directory from windows.  I am sure Linux people are reading this and cringing at this very moment.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: thanks, but no need to be condescending. I was hacking the network parts (no modules yet) in the Linux kernel in 1993 so "Linux people" are different and have very different needs. I am discovering WSL2 as we speak (a great addition, containers basically) and just wanted to make sure MS has not added an extra layer on the accounts. But thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I didn't mean to be condescending.  Sorry WoJ.. that was not intended.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: no worries.

Comment: Since you're using ubuntu, have you given a shot at (from cmd): ubuntu config --set-default-user root?

Comment: @LaurentGosselin: yes. this is what actually triggered the question as I was wondering whether this would not create a mapping "Win user who launched the command" ← → "user root in Linus"